# MeshFaceMaterial not working on certain geometries

Tags: javascript, three.js

three.js

I'm trying to create an icosahedron that has a different color on each face.

```
        var IcoGeom=new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(1);
        var IcoCol=[];
        for (var i=0;i<IcoGeom.faces.length;i++) {
            IcoCol.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:SkyColorRandomizer()}));
        }
        var IcoMat=new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(IcoCol);   
        var myObj=new THREE.Mesh(IcoGeom, IcoMat);
```

*SkyColorRandomizer* is just a function that returns a random color.

Now, here's the issue: It colors all of the Icosahedron the same color (which is random every time), so it doesn't work as intended. Now, if you change IcoGeom to a BoxGeometry instead, it works perfectly well and colors the cube's faces all in different colors, which is very strange. Another thing is: if you go into myObj.material.materials you'll see they all have different colors, but I just don't understand why it doesn't work in the case of the icosahedron, but works perfectly on cubes.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MeshFaceMaterial`, you have to assign a `materialIndex` to each face like so:

```
geometry.faces[ i ].materialIndex = i;
```

A better way to assign a different color to each face, however, is to set face colors:

```
geometry.faces[ i ].color.set( Math.random() * 0xffffff );

...

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors } ) );
```